# Jquery replacing menu text

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

I just need to replace the 'Home' text in my menu with the word 'Back' when it changes to a mobile view.

Any insight or help would be appreciated, just trying to wrap up the last touch on this site and have been having a tough time. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jQuery` is not the best tool to use to handle this. That being said, if you current have no options, you can use [**text()**](http://api.jquery.com/text/) like

```
$('.Back a').text('Back');
```

Comment: Nevermind, tested it out on the phone which I should've done first! Thank you so much for the help!